Add new button to worksheet with Excel Add-in
I am trying to programatically add a new button to worksheet.
I have create a new button in ribbon. On click, that button should create a new button on the worksheet and assign some macro/functionality to it.
    private void createCheckFileButton_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e) // This is the ribbon button.
    {
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet worksheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet;
        Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.Worksheet vstoSheet = Globals.Factory.GetVstoObject(worksheet);

// Add button to worksheet.
        Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.Controls.Button button1 = this.Controls.AddButton(this.Range["A1"], "button1");
        button1.Text = "OK";

    }

I followed THIS but somehow for me it says that "The type or namespace 'Controls' does not exist in Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel."
I am not sure how to fix this. I have installed the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel through NuGet package manager. Is there something else I need?

Create new Add-In project:

Ensure your project has references:

Code which adds button to Excel sheet:
using Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

var ws1 = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets[1];
Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.Worksheet worksheet = Globals.Factory.GetVstoObject(ws1);

if (Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Selection is Range selectedCell)
{
    Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.Controls.Button excelButton = new Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.Controls.Button();
    excelButton.Text = @"Excel button";

    worksheet.Controls.AddControl(excelButton, selectedCell, "MyButton");
}

Result:


Ensure you have installed the correct NuGet package that includes Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.
Install-Package Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office
private void createCheckFileButton_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
{

    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet worksheet = 
        (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet;


    Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.Worksheet vstoSheet = 
        Globals.Factory.GetVstoObject(worksheet);

    var button1 = vstoSheet.Controls.AddButton(vstoSheet.Range["A1"], "button1");
    button1.Text = "OK";


    button1.Click += new EventHandler(Button1_Click);
}

// Example event handler for the button click event.
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Button on worksheet clicked!");
}


Where can I find the Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office? Becsause I don't see it in the NuGet package manager. (Screenshot here: https://imgur.com/a/CDOKZyb)

you can add it also via  in VisualStudio, then add it using the references tab, Add Assemblies/extensions then select Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel and Microsoft Office Tools  Screenprint:

